# A key-generator outputs an encrypted string that only changes the second half - what weaknesses could that expose?

Tags: cryptanalysis

The company I work for provides a software solution. The software is licensed and I have access to the license generator.

We have a company culture of challenging our perceived security but I am a very basic cryptanalyst. I would like to ask for some leads to see if I can prove our license generator needs to be fixed.

Example (not real licenses):

- License #1: abc111
- License #2: abc222

Real licenses are about 600 chars and look very much like an ssh-rsa public key. 
(I can't explain it, they just look like one! If I could show you a real one, I am sure you would agree there is something in common)

Comment: Let's say for a moment that the constant part was not anything "random-looking", but "Here is your license key: ". Would that be any weakness? What's the difference between the former and the latter? Also, is the similarity to a ssh key the fact it uses base64?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've been reading on base64 and I agree, the chars used and the == in the end is what makes me feel they are similar.

Comment: If the entire message is encrypted with the same key, wouldn't cracking one part of it help you to decipher the rest?
If I know one thing in the message that doesn't change, could that help me reduce my brute force attack only to the constant part?

Now, I don't need to go through 600 chars, just 300 until something readable

Comment: if you think this question is silly, please let me know and I will remove :)

Comment: as far as I can see, in this licensing scenario there is no message to decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you called "real licenses" look like ssh-rsa keys is probably just the encoding format for some of them. ssh-rsa keys are base64 encoded, and that might be the only reason. The decode content can really differ based on the license checking algorithm.

You'd probably be better off disclosing your license verification algorithm, and letting people comment on its security/strength which will enable you to improve it in case any issues are found. The fact that the licenses start with the same prefix, on its own, doesn't indicate much about the security of your license verification.
You should also be clear about the assumptions you're making about a potential cracker, and what can they do. That would help assess whether the licensing scheme is secure under those assumptions.